# Execute one or other function when the user swipes right or left on a picture - RxJS

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs, event-handling

## Goal

My goal is to call a function for a slideshow which changes the slide to the next or the previous one. It's that simple

## Code

```
if (location.pathname === "/") {
    var backgroundElement = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    hammer = new Hammer(backgroundElement)
    hammer.on('panright panleft', function (event) {
        var stream = rxjs.fromEvent(backgroundElement, 'deltaX');
        stream.pipe(
            rxjs.map((i) => console.log(i)),
            rxjs.debounceTime(1000)
        )
        .subscribe(j => {
            console.log(j);
            if (j.deltaX > 250) { carousel.next(); }
            else if (j.deltaX < -250) { carousel.previous(); }
        });
    })
}
```

## Errors

None appear apparently. Adding `error => console.log(error);` to the subscription appears to do nothing as well. Nothing is console logged either... I at least want to get a console log...

Comment: Using `map` for just console logging is wrong, use `tap` instead. Also, is `debounceTime` necessary? Have you tried without using it?

Comment: @Andres2142 tried using `tap`, seems to have no effect. `debounceTime` is necessary since otherwise the slides would get continously changed.

Comment: I don't think the `backgroundElement` has the `deltaX` event. Also, I don't think creating a subscription every time the `panright panleft` occurs is a good idea. What event are you expecting from `backgroundElement`?

Comment: @AndreiGătej that's why I tried using event.deltaX, but I think it didn't fully work out either. I am expecting to detect a swipe to the right or left.